# Passing string from UISearchBar to another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm attempting to store the user's input from UISearchBar and then use that string in another view controller. Here's my code:

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    JobDetailViewController *detail =[[JobDetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    self.jobSearchString = self.searchBar.text;

    [detail searchMethod];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.jobSearchString);
}
```

I've stored the string in a text property that I've declared in my header file and I am then pushing to another controller and calling a method. Here's the next view where I attempt to use the string stored:

```
JobbyViewController *mainView = [[JobbyViewController alloc] init];

NSString *searchString = [self.searcherString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];
```

It keeps coming up as (null). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `@property` on your `JobDetailViewController` and set it

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    JobDetailViewController *detail =[[JobDetailViewController alloc] init];
    detail.searchString = self.searchBar.text
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    self.jobSearchString = self.searchBar.text;

    [detail searchMethod];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.jobSearchString);
}
```

Comment: oops, thought the detail had the property haha. Was too obvious.

Comment: Oh geez! I knew I was missing something! Doh! Thank you Bot!